# Having issues pulling data from firebase and storing it in a struct to use in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having a real hard time figuring this out. So if anyone could help would appreciate it. I have some data I want to pull from google firebase and store them into a struct them populate a tableview. But I have having some issues with the table being called before the data is all pulled. Im not sure if I'm using the right database calls for firebase but this is what I have so far.

```
struct provStru {
    var name = String()
    var last = String()
}
var store = [provStru]()

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var name = String()
    var last = String()
    var counter = 0
    while counter<10 {
        ref.child("Prov").child("\(counter + 1)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            if !snapshot.exists() {
                print("doesnt exist")
            } else {
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                name = value?["Name"] as! String
                last = value?["Last"] as! String
                self.store.append(provStru(name: name, last: last)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        counter += 1
    }
```

Then I would like to use that data from the struct to populate the tableview cells. But when I run this code the counter is like an infinite loop. Ive been trying to figure this out for a while. Thanks

This is how the data looks in firebase
[image]

This is what the database looks like then the next value would be 2 then 3 going down

Comment: Reload tableview after data loads into your struct.

Comment: Thats where I need the help. Getting an infinite loop

Comment: You are doing it wrong, you should only get `ref.child("Prov")` and then iterate over it's children, it's inefficient to fetch single child inside the while.

Comment: Are you storing data in an array in Firebase? Prov/0, Prof/1 etc? If so, that's going to be an issue - you should be using something different as your keys; childByAutoId() is the best choice. Also, this is probably not the best way to retrieve data to populate a dataSource array. Can you post a snippet of your Firebase structure as TEXT please NO Images so we can understand your dataset? Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON

Comment: Hey @Jay i updated the question with a picture of what the database looks like

Comment: Using numeric keys like that will very likely getting you 'coded into a corner' You should not use numeric keys - they should be generated with childByAutoId. If you need sorted data, you can create a child node to help with that. Also, doing recursive calls with that while loop may prove to be problematic as well. I would suggest another strategy for loading your data. Perhaps you can expand you question with your use case so we can suggest a better structure and code to load it.